# C++ string analysis

Tags: c++, string

I need to analyze a string in c++ to see if it matches a given template. It's supposed to be a string of characters and dots and slashes etc, and I need to parse it and see if each part is what it's supposed to be.

For example, it's supposed to be a character, then a "/" then some characters, then some other separator (let's say ":" ) and some characters etc. I get a string str and I need a method to analyze it and compare each bit to the given template.

How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like regular expressions would suit your needs. Regular expressions are a standardized way to express patterns to be matched against sequences of characters. Have a look at <regex> for instance.

Comment: Use [`<regex>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) or another regular expression engine. (Of which there are likely many.)

Comment: How about `boost::regex` ?

Comment: Do you have an example of such string?

Comment: let's say it's a standard file path (but I need to look at it solely as a string, parts of which I need to dissect).
So, "c:\directoryname\filename.ext", would be a good example, but I'd get it as a string, and I'd need to compare the parts of the string to some other parts.
Note that I cannot directly view it as a file path, but rather as just a plain old string. (don't ask why... :D )

Comment: For the best answer, we need more information about the problem. For example, will it always be paths? If so, do you want to split it up logically, (root, directory, {directory2, 3...}, filename, extension? If not, can be more specific about how you want to compare the strings? This is what will drive the solution.

Comment: If it's a correct file path (at syntax level) you have to split the string using '/' separator  then process each bit considering that some string may be empty (in case you've a path like /root//////file). To split the string you may wish have a look to split http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with external libraries, you might be able to get away with using the C string tokenizer `strok`.

You could do something like

```
string var = strtok(stringToParse, "./");
while(var!=NULL){
   ...
var = strtok(NULL, "./");
}
```